# Running two users at the same time in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have script in which I log two users in two the web page, one in normal mode and other in incognito mode. What I want is to run **both web drivers at the same time**. I couldn't figure out what to use. I've just defined two separate function. I want them run at the same time. Should I use multithreading, multiprocessing, or something else related to Selenium? My code as follows:

```
def user_qsinav_normal(username, password):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #options.add_argument("--incognito")
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\**\Desktop\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe", options=options)

    driver.get("https://demo.qsinav.com/")
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a").click()

    print("Looking for the email element!")
    user_input = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
    user_input.send_keys(username)

    print("Looking for the password element!")
    password_input = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
    password_input.send_keys(password)

    print("Looking for the giris element!")
    giris_buton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div[3]/button")
    giris_buton.click()

    print("Looking for the sinav modulü element!")
    sinav_modulu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/nav/ul/li[4]/a")
    sinav_modulu.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    print("Looking for the sınavlar element!")
    sinavlar = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/nav/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/a")
    sinavlar.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    print("Looking for the sınavi baslat element!")
    sinavi_baslat = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#datatableExam > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(7) > div > button")
    sinavi_baslat.click()




def user_qsinav_gizli(username, password):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\**\Desktop\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe", options=options)

    driver.get("https://demo.qsinav.com/")
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a").click()

    print("Looking for the email element!")
    user_input = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
    user_input.send_keys(username)

    print("Looking for the password element!")
    password_input = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
    password_input.send_keys(password)

    print("Looking for the giris element!")
    giris_buton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div[3]/button")
    giris_buton.click()

    print("Looking for the sinav modulü element!")
    sinav_modulu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/nav/ul/li[4]/a")
    sinav_modulu.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    print("Looking for the sınavlar element!")
    sinavlar = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/nav/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/a")
    sinavlar.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    print("Looking for the sınavi baslat element!")
    sinavi_baslat = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#datatableExam > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(7) > div > button")
    sinavi_baslat.click()


user_qsinav_normal(USERNAME1, PASSWORD1)
user_qsinav_gizli(USERNAME2, PASSWORD2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use threading:

```
import threading

t1 = threading.Thread(target=user_qsinav_normal, args=(USERNAME1, PASSWORD1))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=user_qsinav_gizli, args=(USERNAME2, PASSWORD2))
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: oh thanks a bunch. In case I want to log in 10-100 users, what would be a better approach? I know it is actually not a good idea asking another question here but...

Comment: Well Selenium needs a lot of RAM and CPU, maybe try to use requests instead of selenium.

Comment: Try to parallelise your test. Threads are only good when you have a very limited process.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll be looking for parallel testing. Selenium Grid seems to be useful for me. I'll be able to log in with 1k users with this, won't I?

Answer (score 2):

Threading works for smaller numbers.

if you are looking for 10-100 of users like you mentioned in the comment (I do not have enough reputation to comment, so answering in the Answer), running them in a single machine is not a good idea.

Selenium grid is implemented for the same reason 1) Running tests in parallel, 2)Running same tests with different browser, OS combinations.

so my suggestion is try selenium grid.

If you are interested docker based solution - you can use Zalenium or [Selenium docker](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/selenium-3)

Comment: Thank you, sir. I'll look for it.